# Couldn't close file in functional way in python3.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I wrote a line of code using lambda to close a list of file objects in python2.6:

```
map(lambda f: f.close(), files)
```

It works, but doesn't in python3.1. Why?

Here is my test code:

```
import sys

files = [sys.stdin, sys.stderr]

for f in files: print(f.closed)   # False in 2.6 & 3.1

map(lambda o : o.close(), files)

for f in files: print(f.closed)   # True in 2.6 but False in 3.1

for f in files: f.close()        

for f in files: print(f.closed)   # True in 2.6 & 3.1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` returns a list in Python 2, but an iterator in Python 3. So the files will be closed only if you iterate over the result.

Never apply `map` or similar "functional" functions to functions with side effects. Python is not a functional language, and will never be. Use a `for` loop:

```
for o in files:
    o.close()
```

Comment: Note also that 2to3 catches this, and will automatically list(...) the map call for you, forcing immediate evaluation.

Comment: 'Never apply map or similar "functional" functions to functions with side effects. Python is not a functional language, and will never be.' I don't see why this wouldn't be sound advice even if python were a functional language. There's simply no point in using map if you're not going to use the result - in any language.

Comment: In purely functional languages functions have no side effects, so a `close()` function cannot exist.

Comment: Purely functional languages are a minority. In ML, you can have side effects as you like... but any ML programmer worth his salt will be avoid them nonetheless. It's not about language enforecements, it's about programming style.

Comment: Your phrasing made it sound as if you were saying "In functional languages it's ok to use map to close each file handle in a list, but not in python because python is not a functional language."

Answer (score 4):

Because map in Python 3 is a lazy iterator. Quoting [the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#map):

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results.

E.g. in Python 2, `map(f, seq)` equivalent to `[f(i) for i in seq]`, but in Python 3, it's `(f(i) for i in seq)` - subtly different syntax, but very different semantics. To make the map variant work, you'd need to consume the iterator. Ergo, it's simpler (and more idiomatic: map, comprehension and generators shouldn't have side effects!) to use an explicit for-loop.

Comment: In my opinion they should have left `map()` alone and made the itertools module `imap()` method a built-in. Instead all 'they' did was introduce a more major incompatibility by change what an existing built-in does.

Comment: Also, leaving `map()` alone and making `imap()` a built-in would have followed the "Explicit is better than implicit" philosophy better.